# How can we stick multi-plots to each other horizontally?

Tags: plotting

I have drawn of the plot of the below list and its fitted curve with `ListPlot` and `Plot` commands respectively.

```
 list= {{1.*10^-6, 0.49759}, {0.000011, 0.491893}, {0.000021, 
0.488727}, {0.000031, 0.486235}, {0.000041, 0.484104}, {0.000051, 
0.482205}, {0.000061, 0.480474}, {0.000071, 0.47887}, {0.000081, 
0.477367}, {0.0001, 0.474729}, {0.0002, 0.463541}, {0.0003, 
0.454677}, {0.0004, 0.447017}, {0.0005, 0.440129}};
listplot=ListPlot[list,Frame -> True,FrameTicks -> {{# 0.0001, #} & /@ Range[1, 5, 1], Automatic}];
plot=Plot[0.4994-3.59821g^0.54032 ,{g,0,0.00055},Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{# 0.0001, #} & /@ Range[1, 5, 1], Automatic}];
```

After that I used `Show` to combine two plots `(finalpresent = Show[{listplot, plot}])`.

**Question:** If I have two (three, four ... in general) pictures from above items, How can I stick them to each other horizontally in a way that the vertical ticks of the second and the third plots aren't present, just the ticks of the first plot. I have used `GraphicsRow` or `GraphicsGrid` but I have not reached something which is desired.

*However, the three plots are not similar generally indeed. I just above shortened the question with one list for `ListPlot` and a one function for `Plot`.*

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `TranslationTransform` on graphics primitives and frame ticks based on `PlotRange` option settings of the input plots:

```
ClearAll[rowLayout]
rowLayout[pad_: 0.05][opts : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{trFs, gridlines, xticks,
   plts = Show[#, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[pad], Scaled[pad]}] & /@ # ,
   paddings = pad {-1, 1}. # & /@ (First /@ PlotRange /@ #), 
   shifts = {1., -1}. # & /@ Partition[Rest @ Flatten[First /@ PlotRange /@ #], 2]},
  trFs = TranslationTransform[{#, 0}] & /@ Accumulate[2 paddings + Prepend[shifts, 0]];
  gridlines = Most @ MapThread[#[{#2 + #3, 0}] &, 
   {trFs, PlotRange[#][[1, 2]] & /@ plts, paddings}][[All, 1]];
  xticks = Join @@ Table[MapAt[trFs[[i]][{#, 0}][[1]] &, 
   (FrameTicks /. Options[plts[[i]], FrameTicks])[[2, 1]], {All, 1}], {i, Length@plts}];
  Graphics[MapThread[GeometricTransformation[#[[1]], #2] &, {plts, trFs}], 
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {xticks, xticks}}, 
   GridLines -> {gridlines, None}, opts, Frame -> True, 
   AspectRatio -> 1/3/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 800]] &;
```

**Examples:**

Using `plot` and `listplot` in OP:

```
rowLayout[][] @ {plot, listplot, plot,listplot}
```

[image]

```
rowLayout[.2][AspectRatio -> 1 / 5 / GoldenRatio] @ {plot, listplot, plot, listplot}
```

[image]

```
plots = {Plot[2 Pi Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
    FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
       {{#, #} & /@ Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, 4 Pi/8], Automatic}}], 
   Plot[5 Cos[x^2], {x, -Pi, 3 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
       {{#, #} & /@ Range[-Pi, 3 Pi, 4 Pi/4], Automatic}}], 
   Plot[x Cos[x], {x, Pi, 4 Pi}, Filling -> Axis, Frame -> True, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
       {Select[Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}][Pi, 4 Pi], Pi <= #[[1]] <= 4 Pi &],
       Automatic}}]};

rowLayout[.1][] @ plots
```

[image]

**Caveat:** It is required that the input plots have explicit settings for `FrameTicks` (as in the examples in OP) to avoid the pain of processing `Automatic` `FrameTicks`.

Answer (score 5):

I would approach this by putting everything in one `ListPlot` and one `Plot`.

```
list = {{1.*10^-6, 0.49759}, {0.000011, 0.491893}, {0.000021, 0.488727}, 
   {0.000031, 0.486235}, {0.000041, 0.484104}, {0.000051, 0.482205},
   {0.000061, 0.480474}, {0.000071, 0.47887}, {0.000081, 0.477367},
   {0.0001, 0.474729}, {0.0002, 0.463541}, {0.0003, 0.454677},
   {0.0004, 0.447017}, {0.0005, 0.440129}};

list2 = {{0., 0.48}, {0.00001, 0.475}, {0.00002, 0.473},
   {0.00003, 0.471}, {0.00006, 0.466}, {0.00009, 0.462},
   {0.00014, 0.457}, {0.00017, 0.455}, {0.00024, 0.449},
   {0.00028, 0.446}, {0.00036, 0.441}, {0.00045, 0.435}};

list3 = {{0., 0.5}, {0.00001, 0.496}, {0.00002, 0.495},
   {0.00003, 0.493}, {0.00006, 0.489}, {0.00009, 0.487},
   {0.00014, 0.482}, {0.00017, 0.48}, {0.00024, 0.476},
   {0.00028, 0.473}, {0.00036, 0.469}, {0.00045, 0.465}};

max = 6.0;
num = 3;

list2 = {max/10000 + #1, #2} & @@@ list2;
list3 = {2 max/10000 + #1, #2} & @@@ list3;

table = Table[{g, 0.4994 - 3.59821 g^0.54032}, {g, 0, 0.00055, 0.00001}];
table2 = Table[{max/10000 + g, 0.48 - 3.9 g^0.58}, {g, 0, 0.00055, 0.00001}];
table3 = Table[{2 max/10000 + g, 0.5 - 3.6 g^0.6}, {g, 0, 0.00055, 0.00001}];

Show[ListLinePlot[List[table, table2, table3], Frame -> True,
  FrameTicks -> {Transpose[
     {Flatten[max # + Range[0, 5] & /@ Range[0, num - 1]]/10000, 
      Flatten[ConstantArray[Range[0, 5], num]]}], Automatic},
  Epilog -> {Darker[Gray], Line[{{max #/10000 - 0.00003, 0},
        {max #/10000 - 0.00003, 1}}] & /@ Range[num - 1]},
  AspectRatio -> 1/(3 GoldenRatio), ImageSize -> 900,
  PlotStyle -> ColorData[97, 1]],
 ListPlot[Join[list, list2, list3], PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.005]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, but unfortunately your solution is not generalizable for me. For example if I have three different plots I don't know how I can use the above code for three different plots!!!!

Comment: @user36028 You just need to add `max/10000` and `2 max/10000` to the x-values of plot 2 and 3 respectively.  The only limitation would be the plot ranges will be the same for all the charts.

Comment: But, what is the role of `table` and `table2`? they are defined while they are not used subsequently!!!

Comment: @user36028 Data and functions for different plots added.

Answer (score 1):

you are too sophisticated. Let's do easier:

```
p = 30;
tks={# 0.0001, #} & /@ Range[1, 5, 1];

st={Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.00051}, Automatic}};
st1 = {ImagePadding -> {{p, 1}, {p, 5}}, 
       ImageSize -> 300,
       FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {tks, tks}}};
st2 = {FrameTicks -> {{None,None}, {tks, tks}}, 
       ImagePadding -> {{0, 1}, {p, 5}}, 
       ImageSize -> 300 - p};
Row@{
ListLinePlot[list, st,st1], 
ListLinePlot[list2, st,st2],
ListLinePlot[list3, st,st2]}
```

[image]