# Plotting Timeseries without gaps or interpolation

Tags: date-and-time, charts, time-series

I have a time series sampled at 5-minute frequency for a financial instrument that trades from 08:30 to 15:15 CT.  No trading takes place outside those hours.

I want to plot the series with the x-axis showing the series timestamps, but without gaps or interpolation.  Neither DateListPlot nor ListLinePlot appears able to accomplish this.

The timeseries looks like this:

[image]

On a large enough timescale a DateListPlot looks fine:

[image]

However, on a shorter timescale the plot shows gaps that are either filled with (meaningless) interpolated values:

[image]

or else are plotted with a large gaps between days:

[image]

ListLinePlot offers no improvement:

[image]

What I want, of course, is to be able to restrict the plot range to the hours of 08:30 to 15:15, i.e. to redefine a "day" or use "session hours" rather than the standard 24-hour clock times.

I have tried using TimeSeriesResample, EventSeries, TradingChart, and a bunch of other things,
but so far there doesn't appear to be a way to accomplish this.

Suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2262295).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First an input dataset with a structure described in OP:

```
dates = Join @@ Table[DateRange[DateList[{2021, 1, i, 8, 30}], 
     DateList[{2021, 1, i, 17, 30}], Quantity[5, "Minutes"]], {i, 1, 4}];

SeedRandom[1]
data = Transpose[{dates, Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 3/2}, Length@dates]]}];

DateListPlot[data, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Use `GroupBy` to get a data set for each day:

```
datasets = Values[GroupBy[data, #[[1, ;; 3]] &]];
```

**1.** We can combine the separate `DateListPlot`s for each day using Lukas Lang's [ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PlotGrid/).

Use `DateListPlot` (specifying horizontal `FrameTicks` explicitly) for each dataset:

```
ClearAll[dateTicks]
dateTicks = Module[{minmax = MinMax[AbsoluteTime /@ #[[All, 1]]]}, 
    Select[First @ minmax <= #[[1]] <= Last @ minmax &]@
     System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[minmax, 6,
   {"YearShort", "/", "MonthShort", "/", "DayShort", " ", "Hour", ":", "Minute"}]] &;

yrange = MinMax @ data[[All, 2]];

dlps = Map[DateListPlot[#, PlotRange -> {Automatic, yrange}, 
     PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, Scaled[.05]}, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
       {MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, #, {All, 2}] & @ dateTicks @ #, 
        MapAt["" &, #, {All, 2}] & @ dateTicks @ #}}] &, datasets];
```

Combine the plots `dlps` with Lukas Lang's `ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"]`:

```
ResourceFunction["PlotGrid"][{dlps}, "MergeAxes" -> "Cut", 
 Spacings -> 10, ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

**2.** Alternatively, we can use the function `rowLayout` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/173003/125):

```
ClearAll[rowLayout]
rowLayout[pad_: 0.02][opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  Module[{trFs, gridlines, xticks, 
     plts = Show[#, PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[pad], Scaled[pad]}] & /@ #, 
     paddings = pad {-1, 1}.# & /@ (First /@ PlotRange /@ #), 
     shifts = {1., -1}.# & /@ Partition[Rest@Flatten[First /@ PlotRange /@ #], 2]}, 
    trFs = TranslationTransform[{#, 0}] & /@ 
      Accumulate[2 paddings + Prepend[shifts, 0]];
    gridlines = Most @ MapThread[#[{#2 + #3, 0}] &, {trFs, 
         PlotRange[#][[1, 2]] & /@ plts, paddings}][[All, 1]];
    xticks = Join @@ Table[MapAt[trFs[[i]][{#, 0}][[1]] &, (FrameTicks /. 
           Options[plts[[i]], FrameTicks])[[2, 1]], {All, 1}], {i,  Length@plts}];
    Graphics[MapThread[GeometricTransformation[#[[1]], #2] &, {plts, trFs}], 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, All}, {xticks, MapAt["" &, xticks, {All, 2}]}}, opts, 
     GridLines -> {gridlines, None}, Frame -> True, 
     AspectRatio -> 1/3/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 800]] &;

rowLayout[][ImageSize -> 600, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio] @ dlps
```

[image]

**3.** We can use `TimeSeriesShift` to shift the dates for each series in `dataset` and to construct custom date ticks:

```
gap = DateDifference[datasets[[1, -1, 1]], datasets[[2, 1, 1]], 
    "Minutes"] - Quantity[60, "Minutes"];

shiftedseries = Table[TimeSeriesShift[datasets[[i]], -(i - 1) gap], {i, 1, 4}];

ticks = TimeSeries[dateTicks @ #] & /@ datasets;

dticks = MapAt[Rotate[#, Pi/2] &, #, {All, 2}] &[
  Join @@ Table[TimeSeriesShift[ticks[[i]], -(i - 1) gap]["Path"], {i, 1, 4}]];

DateListPlot[shiftedseries, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {dticks, Automatic}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Note: all three methods work in version 11.3.0 (windows 10-64b).

Comment: Three great solutions!

Comment: @kglr nice, +1 ! Are you on Community? It'd be great to add your answer [HERE](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2262295)

Comment: Thank you @VitaliyKaurov. I am not on Community. Jonathan already added the answer to his post there.